# trigger SSRS report when finishing a SSIS job

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

A number of SSIS packages have been deployed to the SSI-catalog and are scheduled through SQL Agent jobs.
On the SSRS-server I have created a report that gives me insight in the executions of all SSIS-packages run on the SSIS-server.
I have created a job (Send me report) that, when executed, sends me this report.
I know how to create a jobstep that fires this SQL Agent Job.
I add this jobstep to all the jobs that execute SSIS packages.

However, I am not the only one scheduling packages and not all of my colleagues add this jobstep. The jobs are scheduled and created irregularly. So sending the report every day would be nonsense because sometimes the jobs don't run for a month. Other times, 5 jobs a day are executed.

Is there a way to trigger the job 'Send me report' whenever a SSIS-package finishes running? Regardless of how it was started? Regardless of what the outcome was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a data driven subscription to the report that execute a stored procedure that check if any jobs was executed the day (probably the previous day or running 24 hours, etc.)

Comment: I worked on this idea and expanded it a bit: I created a table that has a datetime column [LastSent]. The proc checks the table if a date is present. If so, it uses that date to check for any executions that have a end_time after that date. If [LastSent] is empty it checks for any execution that has a end_time greater then the beginning of time.

Comment: It then fills [LastCheck] with the max(end_time) + 1 ms. This way I can easily change the schedule on which this proc runs :)